# Oracle CONTAINS query character issue with i, ı, İ, I

Tags: java, oracle, contains

When I run the following query, it works as "%ist%" (notice the dotless i below) and returns wrong results.

```
SELECT * FROM ADDRESS_SEARCH S WHERE CONTAINS(S.TITLE, '%ıst%') > 0;
```

While I was dealing with sorting the NLSSORT with proper locale indication(i.e NLS_SORT=Xturkish) was working pretty well. But now with the CONTAINS method I'm having this trouble with "ı, I" and "i, İ". I want that Oracle recognize my lowercase ı and uppercase I as the correct pair and the same goes for i, İ.

Any suggestions? Or any alternative approaches?

p.s: At the backing code -Java- of the program, during SQL query preparation I tried refactoring the query according to the needed locale though it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `WHERE CONTAINS(LOWER(s.title) , '%ıst%')` ?

Comment: that one throws "DRG-10599: column is not indexed" error

Comment: Try adding an index on LOWER(title)